# Difference between using SDDL or manually creating a security descriptor?

Tags: c++, security, winapi

I need to use the Win32 API to create a folder with particular permissions. As I've been navigating the documentation, I've found two examples that seem reasonable:

1. This example creates a `DACL` using SDDL, adds it to a `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` struct, and uses it to create a folder:

   [Creating a DACL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717798.aspx)
2. This example manually specifies the `SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY`, `PSID`, `EXPLICIT_ACCESS` struct (including the `ACCESS_MASK` etc.), `TRUSTEE`, and so on until the resulting `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` struct is applied to the new object (registry key, in this example's case):

   [Modifying the ACLs of an Object in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379283.aspx)

It seems to me that using SDDL is far easier to use and less bug prone, once you get past the gnarly syntax.

What is the difference, if any, between these two methods? Which is more commonly used in industry?

Comment: As far as the end result goes, there's no difference.  The manual method is a tiny bit faster, but unless you're trying to generate a thousand security descriptors a second that doesn't matter.  The main reason some applications use the manual method is that the code was written before SDDL existed.

Comment: ... although it can sometimes be cleaner to build a security descriptor "by hand" if there are input parameters, i.e., if you don't know in advance exactly what the security descriptor will need to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, you can use either. SDDL is just a "friendly" string for humans to look at. At some point, they have to be converted to their binary equivalent before they can be used by most of the security functions.

SDDL string support was added in Windows 2000, if I remember correctly. More [well-known aliases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379602.aspx) are added in each new Windows version.

Unless you are supporting Windows NT4, or need to use obscure aliases, you can just use SDDL strings if you prefer them.

If speed is more important, the classic way is probably faster.